# Finding when $P(Extinction)$ is $1$ in a Negative-Binomial Offspring Distrubtion

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, markov-process

Consider a branching process $(Xn)_{n≥0}$ but with the offspring distribution given
by $Z ∼ NegBinomial(M, p)$ where $P(Z = n)$ $ ={n+M-1 \choose n}$$(1-p)^M$$(p^n)$

Find the range of values for $p$ such that the population becomes extinct with
probability $1$.

I am unsure of how to proceed from here. Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The extinction probability is $1$ exactly if the expected number of offspring of an individual is $\le1$ (unless every individual always has exactly $1$ offspring).

The expected number of offspring in this case is $\frac{pM}{1-p}$. From $\frac{pM}{1-p}\le1$ we obtain $p\le\frac1{M+1}$.

Comment: In lectures, we were told the extinction probability is the smallest non-negative root of  $\alpha$ $=$ $G(α)$. In a geometric example, the roots of $\alpha$ were 1, and $p/(1-p)$.  The lecturer then concluded that to avoid certain extinction $p<0.5$ by solving it. But when $p<0.5$, the minimum of $1$ and $p/(1-p)$ is less than $1$, as it is in the example you provided. Doesn't this mean that the converse is actually true to your answer?

Comment: @User2121: I'm afraid I don't follow you. I wrote an "exactly if" statement; I'm not sure what you mean by the "converse" of that. In the usual sense, that term only applies to "if" statements and refers to reversing their direction; in an "exactly if" statement, there's no direction to be reversed. Could you spell out more explicitly what you mean?

Comment: Apologies, I meant that that suggested the opposite to your answer, but now I am realising that it supports your answer. Could you offer me any insight as to how I would do it by finding $G(α)$, even if it is more complicated?

Comment: @User2121: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process#Extinction_problem_for_a_Galton_Watson_process) for a derivation of the $\mu\le1$ criterion from $\alpha=G(\alpha)$. You could go through the same arguments that are presented there in general form for this particular case.